# iOS: Sequential interaction

Tags: objective-c, methods, ios5

Preface: I'm very new to objective-c and I am doing simple exercises to learn in order to progress as a developer.

1. Let's say we're playing a memory game. You start with two images: a
   cow and a pig.
2. A word is shown (cow or pig) and you click a corresponding button.

My problem: How do I progress the user to four cards the six and so-on?  Quasi-levels of a game, I guess...or more simply.

Second question: If it were simply one static set of cards (four), how do I allow time between the success message and a reset of the board?

I'm asking more hypothetically, but exact answers would be helpful too so I can understand more about syntax.

If this is confusing, I'm sorry. :) Any information is welcomed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`How do I progress the user to four cards the six and so-on?`

**"Sequence" == "State"**

State is usually maintained with instance variables... so, how about a `numberOfCards` variable? And maybe a `numberOfGamesPlayed` variable as a factor in deciding when to increase the number of cards?

`If it were simply one static set of cards (four), how do I allow time between the success message and a reset of the board?`

Tons of options... two decent ones are:

- `NSTimer`
- `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`

Comment: Could you give me more information on the 'performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:'?

Comment: @KevinBrown Did you google it already?

Comment: I don't understand "performSelector", or what a selector is for that matter.

Comment: A selector is a method name.  Example selectors you may have seen: `alloc` `init` `initWithNibName:bundle:` `viewDidLoad` `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.  Even `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` is itself a selector.